# Convert flash to html5 using Swiffy

Tags: html, flash

I have uploaded an `.swf` file to `Swiffy`. I right-click on the `view conversion` button, and choose to save it on my desktop (saves as `.html`). When I open that `.html` file in `Dreamweaver CC`, the animation loops. The `.fla` file and subsequent `.swf` file, have a action to `Stop();`. It only starts to loop after I run it through `Swiffy`. How can I stop this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use lowercase:

```
stop();
```